# Uncaught ReferenceError: currentPriorityB is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

> ```
> `<select name="builders" id="selectBuilders">
>          <option value="1">Builder 1</option>
>          <option value="2">Builder 2</option>
>          <option value="3">Builder 3</option>
>     </select>
>
>
>
>    <div class="flexchild currentPriorityB**1**">1</div>
>    <div class="flexchild currentPriorityB**2**">2</div>
>    <div class="flexchild currentPriority**B3**">3</div>
> ```
>
> ```
> const currentPriorityB1 = document.querySelector('.currentPriorityB1')
> const currentPriorityB2 = document.querySelector('.currentPriorityB2')
> const currentPriorityB3 = document.querySelector('.currentPriorityB3')
>
>
> let num = 1
> console.log(currentPriorityB+`${num})
> ```

I'm new in Javascript.
I'm trying to select a div using template literals but it says Undefined.

Comment: why do asterisk characters `**` appear inside the class names of your HTML?

Comment: im messing up on stackoverflow posting. just ignore/remove asterisk it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `currentPriorityB` isn't one of your variable names. You can't dynamically retrieve a local variable in order to read it in that fashion.

The only way I believe is to use `eval()` like so:

```
eval(`currentPriorityB${num}`)
```

But would not suggest doing that.

In your case you could just use `num` to generate the css selector for the `querySelector()` call instead

```
let current = document.querySelector(`.currentPriorityB${num}`);
```

Comment: This is my first time  posting on StackOverflow.. 

'let current = document.querySelector(`.currentPriorityB${num}`)'  // I didnt know this is valid. amazing. what is called of this concept?


THank you btw it help alot for reducing lines of code.

Comment: The backticks make a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It is a way to generate strings.